# Can you get IndexOutOfBoundException when the array list you are trying to iterate over is too large? Or is there something wrong with my loops?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, iteration

I am trying to iterate over an arraylist with a least a couple thousands of entries in it. But I was given an IndexOutOfBoundEcxception instead. I've checked my iterative loops and can't really see anything wrong with it (I'm sure that I'm not trying to reach anything outside of the arraylist).  Is there something wrong with my nested for loop or is it that the arraylist I'm trying to traverse over is just too big?

```
    public String filterOrder() throws SQLException{    

        ArrayList<OrderDetails>od= this.getOrderDetails("orderdetails");
        ArrayList<orders>ord=this.getOrders();
        Map<Integer,Double>map=new HashMap<Integer,Double>();
        StringBuffer filter=new StringBuffer();


        for(int i=0;i<=ord.size();i++) {
            double tmp=0;
            for(int j=0; j<=od.size();j++) {

                if(ord.get(i).getOrderNumber()==od.get(j).getOrderNumber()) {

                    tmp=tmp+(od.get(j).getPriceEach()*od.get(j).getQuantityOrdered());

                }
                map.put(ord.get(i).getOrderNumber(), tmp);

            } 
            }

            for(Entry<Integer, Double> entry: map.entrySet()) {
                if(entry.getValue()>5000) {
                    filter.append(entry.getKey()+" has a total value of : $ "+Math.round(entry.getValue()*100)/100.0+"\n");
                }

            }

            return filter.toString();

}
```

context: The two arraylists I used (od and ord) contains objects from two SQL tables, and each objects stored within each of them corresponds to one row/tuple from their respective table. The table "orderdetails" contains 5990 rows, so the arraylist "od" contains 5590 elements. The table "orders" contains 650 rows, so the arraylist "ord" contains 650 elements. When I terminate the loops prematurely(setting the iteration to end way before the last entry of the arraylist), some of the result I expected did come out. It's just that when I iterate over the entire arraylist I get the exception.

The exception message I got from my console goes as follow:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2996, Size: 2996
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at com1028_coursework_sl01586.BaseQuery.filterOrder(BaseQuery.java:150)
    at com1028_coursework_sl01586.QueryTest.main(QueryTest.java:34)
```

What could be the problem? My loops or the arraylist being too big?

Answer (score 2):

size() gives you one greater than the maximum allowed index. You should use < not <= in your conditions. Think about a list with one item in it: the size is 1 but there is only an item at index 0, and nothing at index 1.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! The mistake I made was so basic that I feel a bit embarrassed...

Comment: Don’t worry - everyone makes this mistake every so often!